# Enumerating through a Dictionary.KeyCollection in order

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, ienumerable, key

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The order of the keys in the
>   Dictionary.KeyCollection is
>   unspecified

I am assuming that this is because additions to the Dictionary are placed into some sort of a hash table.

However, I would like to return the .Keys collection from a Dictionary as an IEnumerable (or perhaps as an ICollection) from a method, and enumerate through them in the order they were originally added to the Dictionary.

How best to accomplish this?

(I am using Winforms, .NET 2.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then keep the keys *separately* in a `List<T>`. That original order no longer exists on the dictionary. The list will repeat insertion order.

Comment: I thought about using another List<T> but that seemed like duplication if it was not necessary, and wondered if there was anything I was missing with the Dictionary. However, if that is indeed the way to do it, then no problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `List<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` in place of `Dictionary<K,V>` to maintain order.  The problem with this of course is that it becomes harder to update the value for a key and the fact that you can have duplicate keys.  But that can be handled with these extension methods

```
    public static void AddOrUpdate<K, V>(this List<KeyValuePair<K, V>> list, K key, V value)
    {
        var pair = list.SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(key));
        if (!pair.Equals(null))
            list.Remove(pair);
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, value));
    }

    public static V GetValue<K, V>(this List<KeyValuePair<K, V>> list, K key)
    {
        var pair = list.SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(key));
        if (pair.Equals(null))
            return default(V); //or throw an exception
        return pair.Value;
    }

    public static bool ContainsKey<K, V>(this List<KeyValuePair<K, V>> list, K key)
    {
        return list.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(key));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it would work, but I need to ensure the uniqueness of each Key I add. List.Contains is not as performant as Dictionary.ContainsKey, especially if there are a lot of items I don't think.

Comment: @Andy Yeah it's not ideal, but another option vs. keeping a separate list of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) might do what you need if the key is the insertion order (1, 2, 3,... etc.)